# Opening new page passing parameters without showing them on the URL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm making a MVC C# Web App, and I began wondering whether you could open other pages that need parameters to function, without actually sending them through the URL, which is unsafe, and can lead to some user messing up another registry of the database.

My issue is though, I've never done such a thing, and I cannot find any example of code that does such a thing. The project is run with C# and JS, and the main things I've tried include:

-Doing so with Ajax:

First of all I have a button that calls for a function:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("actionEditStuff", "ControllerName")">Link Text</a>|


function openHorario(id, id_schedule, id_tool) {
    alert(oid, id_schedule, id_tool);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Schedules/actionEditStuff',
        data: {
            id: id,
            id_schedule: id_schedule,
            id_tool: id_tool
        },
        async: 'false',
        success: function (data) {
            //???
        }
    });
}
```

I know there's a way to go to a new page with the success Ajax return, but... That also requires for you to send the parameters through URL.

Obviously, that didn't work, because what the action does in the controller is to **return a view, not a page**. So... I realized that my idea was not very smart, and moved onto somewhere else: Link, but those always end up having to send the parameters visibly through URL.

Is there any way at all to do this in a proper, clean manner?

Thank you!

Comment: what about returning html or View onsuccess()?

Answer (score 0):

@Layan - just to illustrate my comment above, - you could implement something along these lines:

- your client side invokes via ajax

  ```
  ...
  var data = {
          id: id,
              id_schedule: id_schedule,
              id_tool: id_tool
          };
  $.ajax({
          url: '/Schedules/actionEditStuff',
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success: function (view) {
                  //load returned data into div? or popup?
          }
          , error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                  ...
          }
  });
  ...
  ```
- and your controller action

  ```
  public ActionResult actionEditStuff(....parameters...)
  {
          ...
          ...do your magic ...
          return PartialView("~/Views/_PartialViewThatShowsSomething.cshtml", ...pass model...);
  }
  ```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. The issue with this is that the page that it is calling is already made, It is not something I am creating from scratch. So... I would simply want to change a link to a website that is already working, sending parameters through URL, and instead simply send them in another manner. I am not even sure if you can do it. I once worked in a SPA using Express.js, Vue.js, and a ton of other frameworks and it was possible... But I am unsure whether that was possible beacuse one of these amazing frameworks.

Comment: @Layan, - if you need to open other page without "showing" querystring, you could issue a POST request to the other page with parameters you need. You can "redirect" using POST from within ajax.onsuccess() callback